# How do I change a value in a .hbs file

Tags: ember.js

**posts.hbs**

I want to add a suffix to the "onePost.id" value and it has to be done in this file.

```
<br>
<h2> Blog Posts </h2>   
<ul>
{{#each model as |onePost index|}}

    <li id = {{index}}>{{onePost.title}} {{edit-post id = onePost.id + 'suffix' }}
    </li><br>

{{/each}}
</ul>

{{add-new-post}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `concat` template helper:

```
<li id={{index}}>{{onePost.title}} {{edit-post id=(concat onePost.id 'suffix')}}
```

Comment: Blesss up fam, I've been stuck on this for like 2 hoursss

Comment: @AmmarMZ if that's working for you then consider accepting the answer.